Userelationship at the day level is not working in Power Bi
Goal:
Report the total number of 'resolved' and opened cases for an employee for the day prior.
Problem:
The created measure using (Userealtionship) for 'resolved' cases is returning blank data. When the date filter is removed the data displays.
Measure
Resolved = CALCULATE(COUNT('Query1'[number]), USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Date],'Query1'[resolved_at]))
Question:
Is there a DAX formula that can be written to help resolve this? I'm not clear on what to do.
The relationship is established in the model view.
Once the date filter is removed all of the data displays.

What filters do you have applied? What does the evaluation context look like?

Does this answer your question? Power BI DAX Not getting correct results when counting rows with FILTER and USERELATIONSHIP

The date/time format was active on the resolved column in the power query; Whereas, it was active as a date format elsewhere. Once the format was updated in the power query to reflect the same format as the others it worked.
